# Getting value from database using equals while ignoring certain letters

Tags: php, mysql, regex, database, datatables

I have a column in MYSQL named 'text', and it has one value: "He?llo?". I'm trying to get the value "He?llo?" where using the equal to "Hello" to get it. It doesn't equal because "He?llo?" has 2 question marks inside of it, and "Hello" has none. My question is, is there a way to somehow remove the 2 question marks from "He?llo?" before comparing it to "Hello", so that it equals?

```
$text = "Hello";
SELECT text FROM table WHERE text = '$text';
```

Comment: Is this the only example?  (I don't see a 'pattern' here.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replace()`:

```
SELECT text
FROM table
WHERE replace(text, '?', '') = '$text';
```

Comment: I need to replace all question marks, periods, commas, exclamation marks, and more than 1 whitespaces. Like "Hello &nbsp;? &nbsp;? &nbsp;? &nbsp;? &nbsp;?     sir" would be "Hello sir".

Comment: @ellie . . . That is a different question and should be asked as a different question.  Don't ask new questions in comments.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `replace` as many times as you like. But this way of proceeding will require a full table scan, and if your table has many rows this is inefficient.

There are two alternatives :

- look into fulltext index. It could fit your needs, and if it does, it is the most efficient way to solve your problem.
- add a second column and fill it with the cleaned up text. Then you can compare your text in an efficient way,using the indexes.

Comment: I'd definitely do #2 there. Cleaning up the data and ensuring garbage isn't being accepted should be priority.